# How to copy data from one table to another table based on they have some same data in 3rd column?

Tags: sql-server

As question, how to achieve the goal?
For example:

**table 1**

```
place_id     place_name      Invoice_no
100       Sydney            NULL
101       Melbourne         NULL
102       Adlaide           NULL
103       Gold Coast        NULL
104       Perth             NULL
105       Hobart            NULL
```

**table 2**

```
Invoice_id   Invoice_no       place_id
1        NIT1001            100
2        NIT1002            101
3        NIT1002            102
4        NIT1003            103
```

**target table**

```
place_id    place_name  Invoice_no
100         Sydney          NIT1001        
101        Melbourne        NIT1002        
102        Adlaide          NIT1002        
103        Gold Coast       NIT1003        
104        Perth            NULL
105         Hobart          NULL
```

Comment: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Place'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Place'. The duplicate key value is (100            ).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`LEFT JOIN` the two tables `table1` and `table2` to get those unmatched rows from the second table with `invoice_id = NULL`:</strike>

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable(place_id, place_name, invoice_id)
SELECT
  t1.place_id,
  t1.place_name,
  t2.invoice_id
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.place_id = t2.place_id;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/407ba/1)

---

### Edit:

You need to use `UPDATE` with `JOIN` to do this. Something like:

```
UPDATE t1
SET  t1.Invoice_no =  t2.Invoice_no
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.place_id = t2.place_id;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea27a/1)

This will make your table `table1` looks like:

```
| PLACE_ID | PLACE_NAME | INVOICE_NO |
--------------------------------------
|      100 |     Sydney |    NIT1001 |
|      101 |  Melbourne |    NIT1002 |
|      102 |    Adlaide |    NIT1002 |
|      103 | Gold Coast |    NIT1003 |
|      104 |      Perth |     (null) |
|      105 |     Hobart |     (null) |
```

Comment: I received this result, how to fix it?    Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Place'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Place'. The duplicate key value is (100            ).

Comment: @user2210349 What version of SQL Server are you using? It seems like this table `TargetTable` already contains data, what do you want to do in this case of duplicated primary key? ignore this record or update the `place_name` and `invoice_id` or what??

Comment: I am using MS SQLserver 2008, targettable actually is table 1. I want to copy Invoice_no from table 2 into table one only if place_id is matched.

Comment: @user2210349 - OK, Sorry. You need update to do this. See my update.

Comment: Thaks every much, Mahmoud. But could you explain what cause the previous problem? I don't understand it.

Comment: @user2210349 The Primary key constraint of `place_id` what causes the problem, you can't insert more than one value having the same values into a column with a primary key constraint, it makes all the columns' values unique.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213233%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) clause:

```
INSERT INTO targetTable
SELECT a.place_id, a.place_name, b.invoice_no
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.place_id = b.place_id
```